# Array of independent typed pointers in rust

Tags: arrays, struct, rust

I have a custom struct using a type parameter, as such:

```rust
struct Foo<'a, T: ?Sized> {
    parser: &'a dyn Fn(&str) -> Box<T>,
    value: Option<Box<T>>
}
```

As the `T: ?Sized` indicates, the size of an element of type `Foo` does not change depending on the size of `T` (thanks to the `Box`es).

I want to put multiple `Foo` elements in an array, with the elements being able to have a different `T`, and pass it on to a function.

To do it, I tried something along those lines:

```rust
fn parse_all<'a, T>(args: &mut [&mut Foo<'a, T>]) where T: Any;

fn main() {
    let a: Foo<i32> = Foo{parser = ..., value = None};
    let b: Foo<String> = Foo{parser = ..., value = None};
    parse_all(&mut[&mut a, &mut b]);
}
```

Of course it fails, as `a` and `b` have a different `T` type.

The idea is that I don't need to know the exact type of the elements of the arrays, as the `Foo::parser` function pointer will handle them. Additionally, all of them are of a constant size so I shouldn't have size issues.

Can I bypass the fact that each element of an array have exactly the same and have `a` and `b` of different actual types by using `Foo`? (as in C for instance where we can cast a `void*` to any pointer type)

By the way, the array can be of any size, so I can't use tuples as far as I am aware.

Comment: To note, your comment about the size of `Foo<T>` is incomplete. The type doesn't vary with the _size_ of T, but it can still vary depending on the _type_ of T, for example `Foo<String>` vs `Foo<dyn std::fmt::Display>`. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=27648a1241142bc46276bb6d4bbb7f19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All elements of an array must be of the same type. However, that type can be a trait object, such as `Box<dyn FooTrait>` or `&mut dyn FooTrait` for a custom trait `FooTrait`.

You can define the trait and implement it for all your `Foo` types, with some common interface that you can call without knowing the specific type `T`:

```rust
trait FooTrait {
    fn do_something(&mut self);
}

impl<'a, T> FooTrait for Foo<'a, T> {
    fn do_something(&mut self) {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

Because `&mut T` is automatically cast into `&mut dyn FooTrait` if `T: FooTrait`, you can use that instead in your function signature:

```rust
fn parse_all(args: &mut [&mut dyn FooTrait]) {
//                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    for arg in args {
        arg.do_something();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a: Foo<i32> = Foo{parser = ..., value = None};
    let mut b: Foo<String> = Foo{parser = ..., value = None};

    parse_all(&mut[&mut a, &mut b]);
}
```

And it doesn't really matter if all of the `Foo<T>` are the same size, since only the references (which are always the same size) are stored in the array. So you can remove the usage of `Box` as well in your `Foo` struct if you want to avoid that heap allocation:

```rust
struct Foo<'a, T> {
    parser: &'a dyn Fn(&str) -> T,
    value: Option<T>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue with creating an array is not that each `Foo<T>` will have a different *size* - as you pointed our they will be the same. However, each one will potentially have a different *type* which is extra information that would somehow need to be stored, and Rust doesn't support this for arrays.

Since you don't seem to care what the resulting type is during parsing, instead of a generic parameter in `Foo`, you can use `Box<dyn Any>` and then only downcast when you extract the result:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    parser: &'a dyn Fn(&str) -> Box<dyn Any>,
    value: Option<Box<dyn Any>>,
}

impl Foo<'_> {
    fn try_extract<T: 'static>(&mut self) -> Option<Box<T>> {
        if let Some(val) = self.value.take() {
            match val.downcast::<T>() {
                Ok(x) => Some(x),
                Err(x) => {
                    self.value = Some(x);
                    None
                }
            }
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

In your code you don't pass any strings to `parse_all`, but I don't see what that could accomplish, so I've modified it slightly for the working example: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2c443b92d559a793d5aaef3161f135f2)

Note that this won't work if `T` is unsized since [`Box::downcast`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.downcast) requires `T: Sized`.
You will also need to somehow store the types that you want to decode to independently of the array of parsers, but it's difficult to suggest a good approach to do this without seeing more of your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and for the effort you put into it. You assumed well about what `parse_all` should do, I might have removed a bit too much code. `T` should not be unsized in my case, so I'm fine with that. My `Foo` elements will normally be created by hand since what you helped me with will be part of the api of a small argument parsing library I'm doing. For my case, @Frxstrem solution fits better so I'll use it instead, but your solution is still great!